# Oracle Apex 5.0 - Display static image

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I'm new to Oracle Apex and I'm really struggling how to display static images on a desktop application.

I uploaded an image at Shared Components -> Files -> Static Application Files and was given the reference #APP_IMAGES#test.jpg

In my application I then used this reference in the 'source' section by selecting 'item' and then typing #APP_IMAGES#test.jpg in the textbox

When I run the application the image doesn't appear. The regions are visible but no image. I don't even get an error.

I appreciate any help

Comment: Using "item" as the source type won't work because `#APP_IMAGES#test.jpg` is not the name of an item. `#APP_IMAGES#` is a substitution string so must be included in some text that will be rendered in the html of the page without escaping.

Answer (score 12):

There are several options to display an image. But if you want to use an item to display one, you can use an item of the type "Display Image".
In the "Settings" for this item you get a few options on where the image should come from:

- Image URL stored in Page Item Value
- BLOB Column specified in Item Source
- BLOB Column returned by SQL statement

[image: Item identification and settings]

You'd use the BLOB columns when working with images coming from the database, but here you can just use the "Image URL" option.

All you need to do then is to specify the URL in the item's source.
[image: Item source settings]

Obviously there are other methods too. You could indeed just generate the HTML yourself, for example.

Comment: I have a table in apex: emp_data with emp_name and emp_image blob column. If i upload employee image in static files, can ireference it in the blob db column? If yes then how and if no, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 7):

You still need to use html.  Try:

```
<img src="#APP_IMAGES#test.jpg" alt="image">
```

Comment: Thank you Olafur. Works perfectly :)

Comment: Content of static region

Comment: How i can do that in select list , how i can get image from statics file in select list

Answer (score 2):

use

```html
<img src="#APP_IMAGES#flow.png" alt="image">
```

in label. Remember to upload the image in shared components