# Adding a static image to Apex 5.1

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm fairly new to Oracle Application Express and I'm trying to load an image into a page in Apex 5 but with no success.

I've tried loading it as a shared object, both as an application image and workspace image but neither one shows up.

I've added the application item as an image and pointed it to the URL address that I've set up as a shared object and it also does not show up; all that I get is the generic JPEG icon in place of the image. I’ve tried placing it in the content body, the header and in the breadcrumbs bar, each fruitlessly. I've also fiddled around with the image resolution/size/file type; all to no avail.

A colleague with Apex 4 experience told me that everything I’ve tried works in the earlier version.

Any ideas?

P.S. I've already gone through all of the suggestion in this link:

[Oracle Apex 5.0 - Display static image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231112/oracle-apex-5-0-display-static-image)

Comment: Enable debug mode and check for image prefix and
Can you check in browser's DOM (pressing F12) if there is any error.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it (on apex.oracle.com, so that you'd know which version it is - 5.1.4 at the moment).

- upload image through Shared components, into the **workspace images** (I prefer that over *application images* so that I could use all images I have everywhere within the workspace). It is called TEST.JPG
- to set that image as a *region image*, I created a sample page, navigated to region's properties (*region image* is under the "Advanced" section)
- put `#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#TEST.JPG` in there
- run the page
- works fine

If you still can't make it work, create an example on apex.oracle.com, provide credentials so that we could connect and have a look.

Comment: Screenshots / exact menu sequence clicks would be greatly appreciated here... There are hundreds of options in Shared Components to when do I go ?...

Comment: @Jason, files are uploaded in Shared Components - Files section - Static Workspace (or Application) Files. Then click the "Upload file" button and follow instructions.

Comment: Ahh ok then... Thank you... Btw how to you work with CSS in APEX.. For now, I modify the best I can CSS properties in Browser HTML then I add the CSS file for the page in SHared Component then link it to the page only... It's hard to work like that.... Do you have a better way to do it ?