# Oracle APEX how to display an static file image in a listview?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am really new with Apex, and I got this situation, I have uploaded 10 png files to "static application files" section of my application. I have a query  something like this  `select name, imageName,phoneNumber from myTable` the imageName field, holds the name of the static file loaded before.

My problema is, how can I show the image in the listview? I cant find a way

I am using "Application Express 18.1.0.00.45"

I've try this way:

`select name,
'<img src="#APP_IMAGES#' || imageName  ||'.png" alt="image">' as imagenName , phoneNumber from myTable`

This way too

`select name,
'"#APP_IMAGES#' || imagenName  ||'.png"' imagenName ,phoneNumber from myTable`

none of those options work.

any help Will be great

Comment: Can it be answered by this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231112/oracle-apex-5-0-display-static-image?rq=1

Comment: Ive try but it doesn't work  inside a listview,. in the image type I'm using 'image read from url'

Comment: Are you scaping the html? Try to use the developer tools to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and this works for me:

In the Attributes Menu under "Settings" you have to select "Show Image".

Then Select "Image read from URL" as your "Image Type".

Chose the column from your select, which includes the URL (imageName), for "Image URL Column".

Now you can use your code in the select like this:

```
select name, '#APP_IMAGES#' || imagenName ||'.png' as imageName, phoneNumber from myTable
```

Comment: Hi, I've got all you said set, and even I've try to use only one image in the query 

`'#APP_IMAGES#ANULADO.png' as  imagenName` 

that reference is just a copy paste from the shred components/static application files/Reference column of the grid of files

Any other idea?

Comment: Your listview should show the "broken image" icon, as its not loading correctly. If you inspect the image in your browser, what is the image src that shows up there?

Comment: Also are you sure that your variable name is "imagenName" and not "imageName" ? You are using both in your post, so one might be a typo.

Comment: I'm sure the name of the field is the correct, I've checked twice, I've try againg changing to other uploaded file , this time was PROCESADO.png, when the page run, I see the 'X'  (the broken lmage as you said) , I've seen the code  and the code in the HTML page is this:

`<img alt="PROCESADO" src="#APP_IMAGES#PROCESADO.png">`

thanks for your help,... there must be something else wrong

Comment: For me the src shows up like this: ```<img src="...._tbs/r/APP_ID/files/static/v64/imageName.jpg" alt="imageName">```. Are you sure its a png and not a .jpg? Did you copy the reference adresse to the file from the static application files? I don't really know what to tell you, as its working for me .. Maybe try to delete your list view and create it from scratch. Could be you made some changes that prevent it from working now, when you tried to get it running.